# what does the `TEXT` around the format string mean in "printf"

Tags: c, printf

The following prints the percentage of memory used.

```
  printf (TEXT("There is  %*ld percent of memory in use.\n"),
            WIDTH, statex.dwMemoryLoad);
```

WIDTH is defined to be equal to 7.

What does TEXT mean, and where is this sort of syntax defined in printf?

Comment: `TEXT` is probably a macro somewhere. Not standard AFAIK. It's not part of the "printf syntax".

Comment: `TEXT` must be a macro defined somewhere (or possibly a function, but the all-caps name suggests it's a macro). It's not anything in standard C. You'll need to track down the definition in your source file or in something that it `#include`s, directly or indirectly. It probably has something to do with localization, yielding the same message in different languages depending on your settings.

Comment: This is probably using [the `TEXT` macro that is part of `windows.h`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/12/71851.aspx). Also, in the future, please make your title less vague.

Comment: To better understand your problem, it would be good if you give more contextual information like platform and development environment.

Comment: The files included are 
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing but `TEXT` is a `char*` to `char*` function that takes care of translating a text string for internationalization support.

Note that if this is the case then may be you are also required to always use `TEXT` with a string literal (and not with expressions or variables) to allow an external tool to detect all literals that need translations by a simple scan of the source code. For example may be you should never write:

```
puts(TEXT(flag ? "Yes" : "No"));
```

and you should write instead

```
puts(flag ? TEXT("Yes") : TEXT("No"));
```

Something that is instead standard but not used very often is the parameteric width of a field: for example in `printf("%*i", x, y)` the first parameter `x` is the width used to print the second parameter `y` as a decimal value.

When used with `scanf` instead the `*` special char can be used to specify that you don't want to store the field (i.e. to "skip" it instead of reading it).

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, `TEXT` is probably a macro.

To see what they become, simply look at the preprocessor output. If are using gcc:

```
gcc -E file.c
```

Answer (score 0):

TEXT() is probably a macro or function which returns a string value. I *think* it is user defined and does some manner of formatting on that string which is passed as an argument to the TEXT function. You should go to the function declaration for TEXT() to see what exactly it does.

Answer (score 0):

_TEXT() or _T() is a microsoft specific macro.
[This MSDN link says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dzey6h6.aspx)

```
To simplify code development for various international markets,  
the Microsoft run-time library provides Microsoft-specific "generic-text" mappings for many data types,  routines, and other objects.  
These mappings are defined in TCHAR.H.  
You can use these name mappings to write generic code that can be compiled for any of the three kinds of character sets:  
ASCII (SBCS), MBCS, or Unicode, depending on a manifest constant you define using a #define statement.  
Generic-text mappings are Microsoft extensions that are not ANSI compatible.
```

_TEXT is a macro to make a strings "character set neutral".
For example _T("HELLO");

Characters can either be denoted by 8 bit ANSI standards or the 16 bit Unicode notation.

If you define _TEXT for all strings and define a preprocessor symbol "_UNICODE", all such strings will follow UNICODE encoding. If you don’t define _UNICODE, the strings will all be ANSI.
Hence the macro _TEXT allows you to have all strings as UNICODE or ANSI.
So no need to change every time you change your character set.

Answer (score 0):

[TEXT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a unicode support macro defined in `winnt.h`. If `UNICODE` is defined then it prepends `L` to the string making it wide.

Also see [TEXT vs. _TEXT vs. _T, and UNICODE vs. _UNICODE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/12/71851.aspx) blog post.